# Put SELECT into .csv file

Tags: sql, xp-cmdshell

### I'm using this code to create .csv file, but nothing happenes.

```
DECLARE @csvFileName varchar(50)
    DECLARE @SelectOut varchar(8000)

    SET @csvFileName = 'D:\csv Files\' + CAST(year(SYSDATETIME()) AS VARCHAR) +  CAST(month(SYSDATETIME()) AS VARCHAR) + 
                           CAST(day(SYSDATETIME()) AS VARCHAR) + 'IninUsers.csv'

    SET @SelectOut = 'BCP "SELECT DISTINCT u.firstName,u.lastName,wc.name,tw.dateTimeFrom,tw.dateTimeTo                         
                            FROM TA_WhcAssigned tw
                            INNER JOIN TA_Whc wc
                            ON tw.whcid=wc.id
                            INNER JOIN users u
                            ON u.pin = tw.pin
                            INNER JOIN DepartmentsAdmin da
                            ON da.pin = u.pin
                            INNER JOIN Departments d
                            ON da.departmentId = d.parent  
                            WHERE  (year(tw.dateTimeFrom)=2019 or year(tw.dateTimeFrom) = 2018) 
                            ORDER BY dateTimeFrom DESC " queryout ' + @csvFileName + ' -c -T'   



    EXEC xp_cmdshell @SelectOut
```

All I get is how to use bcp syntax:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdqSk.png)

Comment: Checked that your server have a drive D:/ and have access to write to it?

Comment: I put in security Access to that folder to Everyone.

Comment: In work environments the server is often blocked in firewall from access the client zone. Giving AD-permission is just part of the way. You should first try to only verify that you can write any file, before including the rest of the SQL.

Comment: This is my local server. It should have access to everything.

Answer (score 0):

> I resolved my problem. One line of BCP and also some more code for
>   getting columns.
>
> If anyone is interested here is the complete code:

DECLARE @csvFileName varchar(50)
DECLARE @SelectOut varchar(8000)
DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)
DECLARE @sqlLine varchar(8000)

SET @sql='SELECT DISTINCT cast(u.pin as varchar(50)) pin, cast(u.firstName as varchar(50)) firstname,
                          cast(u.lastName as varchar(50)) lastname,cast(wc.name as varchar(50)) name, 
                          replace(convert(varchar(50),tw.dateTimeFrom,103),''/'',''.'')  + '' '' + 
                          convert(nvarchar, tw.dateTimeFrom, 8) dateTimeFrom,replace(convert(varchar(50),tw.dateTimeTo,103),''/'',''.'') + '' '' +
                          convert(nvarchar, tw.dateTimeTo, 8) dateTimeTo
          FROM TA_WhcAssigned tw
          INNER JOIN TA_Whc wc
          ON tw.whcid=wc.id
          INNER JOIN users u
          ON u.pin = tw.pin
          INNER JOIN DepartmentsAdmin da
          ON da.pin = u.pin
          INNER JOIN Departments d
          ON da.departmentId = d.parent
          WHERE  (year(tw.dateTimeFrom)=2019 or year(tw.dateTimeFrom) = 2018) "'

SET @sqlLine = REPLACE(REPLACE(@sql,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')

SET @csvFileName ='"D:\csv Files\' + CAST(year(SYSDATETIME()) AS VARCHAR) +  CAST(month(SYSDATETIME()) AS VARCHAR) + 
                       CAST(day(SYSDATETIME()) AS VARCHAR) + 'IninUsers.csv"'

SET @SelectOut = 'BCP "select ''Pin'', ''First Name'',''Last Name'',''Name'',''Date From'',''Date To'' union all ' + @sqlLine + ' queryout ' + @csvFileName + ' -c -t, -T -S "' + @@servername + '" -d "BoneIDa2"'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @SelectOut

> The only problem that remains is to create comma-separated values csv
>   - so it is UTF-8 and not MS-DOS. Because I have special characters that are presented wrong.